# Analog differential signaling

Tags: analog, noise, brushless-dc-motor, differential, thermistor

I'm a software engineer that sometimes has to deal with some electronics. So I'm by no means an expert...

I want to control a BLDC motor and I have added a thermistor to the windings of the motor so I can ensure the motor doesn't overheat itself. The wires of the thermister (Vcc and GND) go over a twister pair cable to a PCB which contains a voltage divider circuit. But I see a lot of noise once the motor has to do work (e.g. current is drawn). There is an embedded encoder in the motor that sends out a differential digital signal to minimize any noise. I wonder if it's possible to create(or an IC exists of some kind) an analog differential signal for the thermistor voltage reading. Or maybe there is some other way to get a less noisy voltage reading?

The thermistor I'm using is a simple NTC type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a BLDC only works with a controller; that controller should be in charge of temperature monitoring, usually. What controller are you using?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes that controller has a thermistor input. That's how I can tell the input is noisy. I also checked with an teensy. This doesn't have anything to do with the controller...

Comment: Show an oscilloscope shot of the noisy voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka Will do once I'm at work on monday.

Comment: Need to see both lines with respect to ground where the receiver is.

Comment: Simplest way would be some capacitance, and to differentially measure the ground and signal, instead of a single ended measurement, this way any noise on the wiring should cancel